# undefined reference to glCompressedTexImage2D

Tags: opengl, textures, dev-c++

I am trying to load some .dds textures for my game.
My IDE is Dev-C++ with GLUT 7.6 installed.
When I use  OpenGL functions like glTexImage2D() or glVertex2f() my programs compile normally but when I try any of the glCompressedTexImage functions the linker tells me that there's an undefined reference to it.
like that:    [Linker error] undefined reference to `glCompressedTexImage2D@32'.
I am linking my project only with libopengl32.a, and I am using Win API for the window.
Does I need to add another library in the linker options or my OpenGL version is too old ?

Comment: How are you creating your window?  I'm thinking the GL version it's giving you does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows platform opengl32.lib provides functions only for a very old GL version (1.1 or something like that). If you want functionality from newer OpenGL version, then you should get pointers to missing functions using wglGetProcAddress.

However, this is too much hassle. So instead of that you can use OpenGL extension library ([GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLEE](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php)) to get missing function addresses for you. It is a better idea to use GLEW instead of GLEE, since GLEE looks abandoned.